# Which compiler does JasperCompileManager use?

Tags: java, jar, jasper-reports, javac

I have a Java Application that compiles a jasper template file *.jrxml at runtime and then uses it to fill a report and generate a PDF. 

Since I need to target the 1.6 JDK I'm using eclipse's compliance settings to choose said version and lastly build a jar which is supposed to run in production.

This works fine on my dev machine however when I try to run the jar on prod

`$ /usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.6.0/bin/java -jar mreporte-crc.jar`

I am getting the following error message:

`Class file has wrong version 50.0, should be 49.0.`

On the line:

`JasperCompileManager.compileReport(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("Report.jrxml")`

I have verified the version of Java and javac at the route /usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.6.0/bin/ and it is 1.6.0__22-b04 for both.

However the *default* java and javac version on the server is 1.5.0__19.

Is the JasperCompileManager using the default javac compiler instead of the one at/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.6.0/bin/ which I'm using to run the jar?